# How did our Prophet Muhammad (PBHU) die?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, death, seerah

Salam Alaikum,
it's true that the Prophet died because the affects of poison? (which seems to have many flaws) 
Or did our Prophet die because a natural cause?

Comment: For the people who doesn't want to or can watch the video (it could be deleted from YouTube), could you summarize what is said in the video and what you find disturbing about it.

Comment: It basically that Prophet Muhammad (PBHU) was poisoned. I think that was their biggest argument.

Comment: If your question is asking if it's true that the prophet died because the affects of poison then please describe that in your question,  so it is clear for everyone that might want to address the question

Comment: Fundamentally changing a question after it's already been posted and answered is inappropriate and disrespectful of the time and effort people have spent on the original question. If you have a new question, post it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

There's reliable ahadith that the Prophet was poisoned after the [Battle of Khaybar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Khaybar):

> Narrated Abu Huraira: When Khaibar was conquered, a (cooked) sheep containing poison, was given as a present to Allah's Apostle.
> <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 4249](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/64/284) (see also [Sahih al-Bukhari 3169](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/58/11))</sub>

An important point here is the long time difference between when the Prophet was poisoned (in the year 628), and when the Prophet died (in the year 632).

Ordinarily, scholars (e.g. [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/32762), [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=260611)) conclude that Muhammad died from the poisoning, but his death was delayed by Allah until he completed his mission.  One fatwa writes:

> Ibn Masud (Allah be pleased with him) felt that the Prophet [peace be upon him] had died as a martyr, the delay in the poison’s effect being a prophetic miracle.  Allah Most High thus preserved His beloved Messenger until his mission was completed, and then, to honor him, caused him to die a martyr.  [al-Zurqani, Sharh Mawahib Laduniyya] 
> <sub>Abdullah Anik Misra, [SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2011/08/24/did-the-prophet-muhammad-die-as-a-martyr/)</sub>

This conclusion is supported by the hadith:

> Narrated 'Aisha: The Prophet in his ailment in which he died, used to say, "O 'Aisha! I still feel the pain caused by the food I ate at Khaibar, and at this time, I feel as if my aorta is being cut from that poison."
> <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 4428](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/64/450)</sub>

In any case, it's not as straightforward as "he was poisoned to death".

---

There are alternative scholarly views:

> In conclusion, it seems most likely that the Prophet (pbuh) died of natural causes and was not poisoned. And God knows best.
> <sub>Sheikh Mansour Leghaei, [Ask The Sheikh](http://www.askthesheikh.com/was-the-holy-prophet-poisoned-or-killed-did-he-die-a-natural-death/)</sub>
>
> He was poisoned by his two wives, [Aisha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aisha) and [Hafsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafsa_bint_Umar), ...
> <sub>Shaykh [Yasser Al-Habib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yasser_Al-Habib) ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HiMgW9yd7w))</sub>

This later view appears in Shia Islam:

> Several prominent Shia accounts even report that she, along with Hafsa, brought about Muhammad’s death by giving him poison.
> <sub>[Shia view of Aisha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shia_view_of_Aisha), Wikipedia</sub>

Comment: I recommend not listening to Yasser Al-Habib. This guy hates Aisha so much!

Comment: You should also add that it does not matter how the prophet died. He could have been martyred in battle but that would not make Islam any less true. 3:144

Comment: @Casanova — Yasser Al-Habib curses all companions, including 'A'isha. He is neither a source for Sunnis, nor for Shi'as (as he also cursed a number of marjis). He is out there on his own, with his views revered only by his group of followers, no one else.

Comment: Yes you are right!

Comment: @Rebecca If you knew Yasser Al-Habib misleading why persist to put it there (My edit was rejected because it's a major edit and I understand that. https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52690)? Are you a sunni?